# What are available Python libraries for Interpretable ML?

Tags: machine-learning, python, interpretation

I recently become familiar with Interpretable ML and I found some libraries like LIME. I would be thankful if you can suggest to me some libraries and what are the advantages of each library.

Comment: I have been maintaining a relevant answer in Artificial Intelligence SE, [Which explainable artificial intelligence techniques are there?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/which-explainable-artificial-intelligence-techniques-are-there/24138#24138)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of the most common Python packages for interpretable machine learning:

- [Lime](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) - Can explain the prediction of any machine learning classifier.
- [SHAP](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) - A game-theoretic approach to explain the output of any machine learning model.
- [ELI5](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) - Explain the weights and predictions of a variety of machine learning models.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest [Dalex](https://github.com/ModelOriented/DALEX) as it has a very easy workflow and has both Python and R APIs.

Also [Interpret-ML](https://interpret.ml/) from Microsoft has very good features.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/81993)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).